# Keybinding for EasyAlign interactive prompt is not working

Tags: key-bindings, neovim

I'm trying to use [`junegunn/vim-easy-align`](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align) to vertically align some text.

EasyAlign has an [interactive-mode](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align#interactive-mode) which means you can invoke EasyAlign, it prompts for a key, and then aligns around whatever key you enter.

eg: given the following text:

```
foo = bar
hello = world
a = b
something = this
```

You can visually select the 4 lines, and then enter interactive mode using `:EasyAlign`, then hit `=`, and it will result in:

```
foo       = bar
hello     = world
a         = b
something = this
```

Manually this works great, but when I attempt to add a keybinding it fails.

I would like to bind `:EasyAlign` to `<leader>xa` in visual mode.

This is the command I've used:

```
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('v', "<leader>xa", "<cmd>EasyAlign<CR>", { noremap=true, silent = true })
```

When I hit `<leader>xa` I can see the EasyAlign interactive prompt in the message area, but when I then hit `=` nothing happens.

How can I bind `<leader>xa` to open the EasyAlign interactive prompt, and then have it align around whatever key I enter?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble that worked!! Thank you! If you would like to write this in an answer I'd gladly accept. Where can I read up on what the difference is here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `:` instead of `<cmd>`; it’s possible switching mode is intended here. Read about the difference at `:help <cmd>`.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this myself while doing my vimscript-to-lua conversion. For whatever reason, you can't use `noremap=true`. Here's how I have it in my setup:

```
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap('v', '<Enter>', '<Plug>(EasyAlign)', {})
```

Comment: You have to let `<Plug>` mappings go through recursive processing, in general, so that’s one of the few times you want (for example) `nmap` instead of `nnoremap`

Comment: I've never really understood the purpose of `<Plug>`. I guess I'll have to read up on it. Why would junegunn recommend using `<Plug>`, as indicated here: `:h easy-align-1-using-plug-mappings` or https://github.com/junegunn/vim-easy-align/blob/master/doc/easy_align.txt#L158